# How to link variable from master dataset to detail dataset in SPSS

Tags: statistics, data-science, spss

I want to link between master and detail table variables. Below I have provided datasets and expected output

**Table dataset:**

```
**Master Table (Movie)**

ID          Title
1       A Quiet Place
2       Cruella
3       Black Widow
4       The Night House


**Detail Table (Ratings)**    
// here M_1 = Master table ID 1, M_2 = Master table ID 2. like this
// M_(x) columns contains rating values (0 - 5)

UserId     M_1      M_2       M_3      M_4
1           3        5         2        4
2           2        3         1        2
3           4        4         3        1
4           1        3         4        2


**Expected Output (Frequency Table)**

A Quiet Place
Rating      Frequency
1              0
2              1
3              1
4              1
5              1


Cruella
Rating       Frequency
1              1
2              2
3              1
4              0
5              0

so on....
```

Note: I can't modify detail table M_1, M_2 .... variable labels to movie title because it is very large data

Comment: Could you detail a bit more how rating column is calculated. Seems each user has a top 4 information (M_x).

Comment: Rating column is rating given by users (out of five) against movie

Comment: @jiandercy let me know if you need more details.

Comment: If I understand right what you need is a way to automate adding variable labels according to the movie name list?

Comment: yes ! @eli-k that's right

Comment: See my solution below

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax to create variable labels automatically from your list. I assume your original data (as you presented in your post) is stored in two datasets: `master_table` and `detail_table`.

```
dataset activate master_table.
string cmd (a100).
compute cmd=concat("var labels M_", ltrim(string(ID, F8)), ' "', Title, '".'). 
write out="path\create labels.sps" /cmd. 
execute.
dataset activate detail_table.
insert file="path\create labels.sps".
```

The syntax uses your list to create a new syntax with variable labels commands for each of the names in the list, and then runs these commands in your details dataset.
Note - replace "path" with actual path.